# how to import both text and images to pubspec yaml

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, dart-pub, pubspec

I want to import both font and images to `pubspec.yaml` but it gives me an error why?
here is my code

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/posts/
    - assets/stories/
    assets/avatars/
  fonts:
    - family: Klavika
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts\KlavikaBold.otf
```

Comment: Could you also include the error?

Comment: the '-' in assets/avatars/ is missing it should be '- assets/avatars/'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pubspec.yaml` is sensitive to indentation. You have missed `-` for your avatar folder. Hope the code below should work.

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - assets/posts/
    - assets/stories/
    - assets/avatars/
  fonts:
    - family: Klavika
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts\KlavikaBold.otf
```

Answer (score 1):

Without "-" before assets/avatars/, dart understand that you want to add assets at directory `assets/stories/%20assets/avatars/` and of course this cause error.

You should follow doc https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images then add "-" before assets/avatars/ like previous answer of Bashistha.